# Tracking the Unique Devices after user installs them on their iOS devices

Tags: xcode, ios7, uuid, udid, nsuuid

We have a app that keeps track of unique users. Earlier we tracked them using the UDID. As Apple deprecated the use of UDID and it no longer supports the use of UDID.

The problem here is when a user installs the app we can know the users unique id by the Vendor identifier.

Our app functions this way.
When a new user installs the app then a vendor id is generated and sent to server. this is unique for that user. but when the same user uninstalls and again re-installs the app. again a new vendor id is generated.

How can I prevent the duplication of the user id's.
Is there any alternative solution for this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Get UUID and then store them in keychain of device. Now use UUID in keychain as unique identifier.